# Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command-Using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, security

Will need your advice on the following coding. My program went through Static application security testing and the line

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(SP);
```

Was flagged as

> Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command.

I assume this is a false positive as I am using parameterized query and stored procedure. Just need to confirm. Thank you.

```
private DataSet ExecuteC()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    
    DateTime startDateMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-Properties.Settings.Default.ModifiedMonthsBacklog);
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(startDateMonth.Year, startDateMonth.Month, 1);
              
    string SP = "SP_abc";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(SP);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dStartDate", startDate));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dEndDate", endDate));
         
    return ExecuteConnection(cmd, exportType);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the flag means but there are a couple of things that can be improved in your code right away: 1. SqlCommand is an `IDisposable` - so add a `using` statement for it and 2. Use an overload of `Add` that takes in the parameter name and type instead of explicitly creating new instances of SqlParameter, and then fluently add their respective values. (so `cmd.Parameters.Add("@dStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate`)

Comment: Flagged by what? That's not an ADO.NET message. Yes, this is a false positive. BTW there's no reason to define the `cmd` variable at the top. In fact, this can cause serious bugs because it widens the scope of the variable and can lead to accidental reuse of the variable's contents. `var cmd = new SqlCommand(SP);` is better

Comment: Maybe it won't trigger if you declare it `const string`

Comment: Flagged by Semgrep. Noted on the above remarks that I can improve on it .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Or `using var cmd = ...` One hopes that the connection is not being cached either.

Comment: @Charlieface if the connection is disposed, commands and readers are also disposed.